# I would like to separate a character string with spaces XX XXX XXX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I am a very young developer and I cannot find the solution.

I have an entry in which the user enters a number which should be separated like this XX XXX XXXX

By doing this I separate the numbers like that XXX XXX XXX
but that's not what i want

`result = '123456789'.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1 ");`

I would probably need something like this, but I'm blocking it

`.replace(/"(..)(...)(....)","$1 ""$2 ""$3 "/g)`

If you could give me any help that would be very appreciated.

Comment: I found the answer 
```.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{4})/g, '$1 $2 $3')```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, it really helps me.
now I would like the user to be able to modify the numbers entered in the input. For the moment, if he erases a number, he cannot replace it.

Comment: ```const [beneficiary, setBeneficiary] = useState('')
      <InputText
        maxLength={9}
        value={beneficiary.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{4})/g, '$1 $2 $3')}
        onChange={(e) => {setBeneficiary(e.target.value) }}
      />```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply look for the groups you require (2 digit, 3 digit, 4 digit) and replace as necessary

```js
const result = "123456789".replace(/(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{4})/,"$1 $2 $3")
console.log(result)
```

The above assumes they're always numerical, of course, if not you could use a different match as appropriate but the idea remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

You need a regular expression without quotes and a replacement string with only the groups.

```js
const result = '123456789'.replace(/(..)(...)(....)/, '$1 $2 $3');

console.log(result);
```